# Unable to save calendar events to Darwin Calendar server

Tags: python, darwin, caldav

I am trying to have a calendar server, and I have picked Darwin's open source Calendar server as the server. I have followed the steps mentioned in the [Quick start](http://trac.calendarserver.org/wiki/QuickStart) page and I was able to get the server running.

Then I wrote the following python script to save a calendar event

```
from datetime import datetime
import caldav
from caldav.elements import dav, cdav

# Caldav url
url = "http://apprentice:apprentice@localhost:8008/calendars/users/apprentice/calendar/"

vcal = """BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Example Corp.//CalDAV Client//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:1234567890
DTSTAMP:20100510T182145Z
DTSTART:20100512T170000Z
DTEND:20100512T180000Z
SUMMARY:This is an event
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
"""

client = caldav.DAVClient(url)
principal = caldav.Principal(client)
calendars = principal.calendars()
if len(calendars) > 0:
    calendar = calendars[0]
    print "Using calendar", calendar

    print "Renaming"
    calendar.set_properties([dav.DisplayName("Test calendar"),])
    print calendar.get_properties([dav.DisplayName(),])

    event = calendar.add_event(vcal)
    print "Event", event, "created"

    print "Looking for events in 2010-05"
    results = calendar.date_search(
        datetime(2010, 5, 1), datetime(2010, 6, 1))

    for event in results:
        print "Found", event
```

And I am getting the following error

> File "nodesets.py", line 22, in 
>       principal = caldav.Principal(client)   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/caldav/objects.py", line 256, in
>   **init**
>       cup = self.get_properties([dav.CurrentUserPrincipal()])   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/caldav/objects.py", line 151, in
>   get_properties
>       raise Exception("The CalDAV server you are using has " Exception: The CalDAV server you are using has a problem with path handling.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would start by trying

```
url = "http://apprentice:apprentice@localhost:8008/"
```

Comment: Tried that. does not work. I added another condition in objects.py file of the caldav module. I noticed there was a problem in the keys getting generated there. Once I added that condition there, then it seemed to be working perfectly